# Show hidden Characters in PDF

Tags: preview, ocr

I made some optical character recognition on a scanned PDF File. The original document contains special characters like öäü and so on. The problem is that sometimes the characters get recognized wrong (ex. ö=u), Preview will then let me highlight the character image ö but when copying the character it will output u.

Can Preview show me what the actual recognized characters are without the Image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Preview cannot do this. What you have is a PDF document where the original image is overlaid on the recognized text. You will need a PDF editor to delete the image.

You could also select and copy the entire document, then paste it into a text editor and review the recognition there.